# Define One to Many Relationships with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, one-to-many

I'm looking for a way to set up a one to many relationship between 2 tables. The table structures is explained below but I've tried to leave everything off that has nothing to do with the problem.

Table `objects` has 1 column called `uuid`.

Table `contents` has 3 columns called `content`, `object_uuid` and `timestamp`.

The basic idea is to insert a row into `objects` and get a new `uuid` from the database. This `uuid` is then used stored for every row in `contents` to associate contents with objects.

Now I'm trying to use the database to enforce that:

- Each row in `contents` references a row in `objects` (a foreign key should do)
- No row in `objects` exists without at least a `row` in `contents`

These constraints should be enforced on commit of transactions.

Ordinary triggers can't help probably because when a row in the `objects` table is written, there can't be a row in `contents` yet. Postgres does have so called `constraint triggers` that can be deferred until the end of the transaction. It would be possible to use those but they seem to be some sort of internal construct not intended for everyday use.

Ideas or solutions should be standard SQL (preferred) or work with Postgres (version does not matter). Thanks for any input.

Comment: The primary key for "contents" is {object_uuid,the_timestamp} ? BTW *why* do you want a separate "objects" table; IMHO it serves only as a domain for contents->object_uuid. BTW2: the constraint you want *can* be implemented with rules (is that allowed, since it is postgres-specific?), but there still is a problem with supplying a value for "content", on insertion of a fresh row. (I presume now() is good enough as an initializer for the_timestamp)

Comment: @wildplasser The reason for multiple tables is that there can be any number of contents and the actual tables contain more stuff than the example in this question. The solution outlined below solved the problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that other than foreign key constraints; no constraint can reference another table.

Your best bet is to denormalize this a little and have a column on `object` containing the count of `contents` that reference it. You can create a trigger to keep this up to date.

`contents_count INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

This won't be as unbreakable unless you put some user security over who can update this column.  But if you keep it up to date with a trigger and all you're looking to avoid is accidental corruption, this should be sufficient.

**EDIT**: As per the comment, `CHECK` constraints are not deferrable.  This solution would raise an error if all the contents are removed even if the intention is to add more in the same transaction.

Comment: CHECK constraints are not deferrable according to your link. So I ended up adding a column to `objects` to hold the required number of contents (since my schema is more complex than the example and allows for groups of contents) and one column to hold the actual number of content groups present. Inserting into `contents` updates the actual number in the `objects` table. A foreign key constraint from `objects(uuid, actual)` to `objects(uuid, required)` along with a unique constraint can replace the check constraint and be deferred. Your idea with counting the contents solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to do is normalize a little bit more. You need a third table, that references elements of the other tables. Table `objects` should have its own uuid and table `contents` sholud have also its own uuid and no reference to the table `objects`. The third table should have only the references to the other two tables, but the primary key is the combination of both references.
so for example you have an uuid of the table `objects` and you want all the contents of that uuid, assuming that the third table has as columns object_uuid and content_uuid, and the table contents has its own serial column named uuid, your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM thirdtable,contents 
   WHERE thirdtable.content_uuid = contents.uuid AND thirdtable.object_uuid=34;
```

Then you can use an on insert trigger on every table

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON contents
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_check_function();
```

and then in function my_check_function() delete every row in `objects` that is not present in the third table. Somebody else answered first while I was answering, if you guys like my solution I could help you to make the my_check_function() function.

Comment: Inserting into the `objects` table would drop the row again because `my_check_function` would find that the third table does not contain it. The problem was that ordinary triggers could not be used since they would be executed before an insert into the second table could be done.